# Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property ‘width’ of undefined Wordpress Salient Theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a problem, and for once I think you’ll can’t unfortunately solve it … 
I get an error “Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property ‘width’ of undefined” in my console..

Which slowing my site a bit, and I would solve it but I don’t know where it can come or if I should change the source code or whatever …

Here’s all the information about the error and file it speaks, and the targeted source code (line 376 exactly) : 
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/760911probleme.jpg

If you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Best Regards, Playzare

Comment: Is any of this your own code? If so, comment off your calls to isotope until you find the offending call, and then look hard at what you're doing in that call that might lead to errors. Are you passing in empty elements, or null, or an object that's missing properties, etc. etc.

Comment: Unfortunatly, it's not my own code, it comes from a wordpress theme : salient wordpress theme, and the error is done by a plugin, but if there is this error i think it's because this code isn't optimized... Thanks for your comment !

Comment: let the theme builders know, stackoverflow's probably the wrong place to ask then